# How should I control the idle time of my app for this use case in BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I need to control the idle time of my app when the user is logged in.

This is my use-case:

> When the idle time reaches the 4 minutes, an options dialog should be
>   displayed with  the option to close it.
>
> IF the user closes the dialog the dialog just closes
>   ELSE
>   the timer for the idle time should just continue and when it reaches the 5 minutes (1 minute later) the dialog must be closed.
>
> a new message dialog must be displayed for 5 seconds.
>   after the 5 seconds the new dialog must be closed.
>
> I must execute some code I already have to logout the user.

Actually, I have a working code but it's kind of nebulous.

To know the idle time, I do this: **DeviceInfo.getIdleTime()**.

The method is controlled by a **RealtimeClockListener**, so when the user logs in, I do *UiApplication.getUiApplication().addRealtimeClockListener* and when it logs out I just do 
*UiApplication.getUiApplication().removeRealtimeClockListener*.

I can post my code if needed but I really would like to see a new approach someone could suggest.

## Update

This is the solution I'm using.

```
public static RealtimeClockListener realtimeClockListener = new RealtimeClockListener() {
        int _4Minutes = 60 * 4;
        int _5Minutes = 60 * 5;
        int _5Seconds = 5 * 1000;
        Dialog dialog4Minutes = null;
        Dialog dialog5Minutes = null;
        Timer timer5Seconds = null;
        TimerTask timerTask5Seconds = null;
        public void clockUpdated() {
            if ( Application.getApplication().isForeground() ) { 
                appInactiveTime = (int) DeviceInfo.getIdleTime(); 
                inForegroundFlag = true; 
            } else { 
                if ( inForegroundFlag ) { 
                appInactiveTime = 0; 
                } else { 
                    appInactiveTime = appInactiveTime + 60; 
                } 
                inForegroundFlag = false; 
            }
            synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) {
                UiEngine ui = Ui.getUiEngine();
                if ( appInactiveTime < _4Minutes ){
                    if ( dialog4Minutes != null ) {
                        dialog4Minutes.close();
                        dialog4Minutes = null;
                    }
                }
                if ( appInactiveTime < _5Minutes ){
                    if ( dialog5Minutes != null ) {
                        dialog5Minutes.close();
                        dialog5Minutes = null;
                    }
                }
                if ( appInactiveTime >= _4Minutes && appInactiveTime < _5Minutes ) {
                    if ( dialog4Minutes == null ) {
                        dialog4Minutes = new Dialog("Stay Logged In?", new String[] {"SI", "NO"}, new int[]{1,2}, 2, null);
                        ui.pushGlobalScreen(dialog4Minutes, 1,UiEngine.GLOBAL_QUEUE);
                    }
                } else if ( appInactiveTime >=_5Minutes ) {
                    if ( dialog5Minutes == null ) {
                        dialog5Minutes = new Dialog("You will be disconnected", new String[] {"OK"}, new int[]{1}, 1, null);
                        ui.pushGlobalScreen(dialog5Minutes, 1,UiEngine.GLOBAL_QUEUE);
                        timerTask5Seconds = new TimerTask() {

                            public void run() {
                                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                                    public void run() {
                                        dialog5Minutes.close();
                                        try {
                                            //logout in communication manager 
                                            //pop to initial screen
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            //force logout (2nd way)
                                        }finally{
                                            UiApplication.getUiApplication().removeRealtimeClockListener(realtimeClockListener);
                                        }
                                        timerTask5Seconds.cancel();
                                        timerTask5Seconds = null;

                                        timer5Seconds.cancel();
                                        timer5Seconds = null;                                       
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        };
                        timer5Seconds = new Timer();
                        timer5Seconds.schedule(timerTask5Seconds, _5Seconds);
                        if ( dialog4Minutes != null ) {
                            dialog4Minutes.close();
                            dialog4Minutes = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Thanks Peter Strange!

Comment: Does your app need to be 4 minutes in the foreground to have this happen, or 4 minutes even if the user gets a phone call and spends 4 minutes talking with your app in the background?

Comment: yes Peter, I forgot to mention that. It doesn't matter if the app is in the background or in the foreground for the idle time.

Comment: As noted in your other Thread, I don't think the "synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock())" block is needed.  In this case it does not hurt, however using it can hurt in other circumstances, so please use this with caution.

Comment: I wonder if there are some end cases not well handled. (1) I think you need dialog close listeners to stop the timeout if the user answers your dialog4Minutes and dialog5Minutes (2) your 5 second Timer does not remove the reference to dialog5Minutes meaning that future tests "if ( dialog5Minutes == null )" will always find an exiting Dialog (3) your 5 second time should check before doing this: dialog5Minutes.close(); I appreciate it is unlikely but a race condition might mean the other processing has removed it.  Could be wrong on any of these.  Just trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that you will use the RealtimeClockListener as a 'tick' that wakes up your application every minute.  This works and is efficient, but does mean that your time out time will not be exactly 4 minutes - its actual duration will depend on whereabouts in the 'minute' the user becomes idle.

The trick is to determine what state your application is in when the tick happens or more accurately.  I think the following sample code describes this, assuming that initially appInactiveTime is set to 0 and inForegrounFlag is true.

if ( Application.getApplication().isForeground() ) {
appInactiveTime = DeviceInfo.getIdleTime();
inForegrounFlag  = true;
} else {
if ( inForegrounFlag ) {
// Was in foreground, start idle timing from now
appInactiveTime = 0;
} else {
appInactiveTime = appInactiveTime + 60;
}
inForegrounFlag = false;
}

I believe that using this code, appInactiveTime can now be used to find out if the app has been inactive for more than 4 minutes, by comparing it with 240 (60*4).  .

At this point, your App should create and display a Global Screen, if you want it to show regardless of whether the app is in the Foreground or not.  Then on the next tick, you can decide if you want to dismiss this screen or not, or if the user has dismissed it. I have the impression you need help with the timing rather than this part of the processing, so I will leave this with you.

Comment: hi Peter, sorry for the delay. I'm still working on your suggestion. It's just that
I'm stuck trying to manage the display of the dialogs correctly. Please take a look at my question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578986/how-to-close-a-global-dialog-and-display-another-in-blackberry

Comment: hi Peter! Thanks for all the help! I posted the whole solution including the help you provided in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578986/how-to-close-a-global-dialog-and-display-another-in-blackberry.